# Nodejs - How to send data from html to hapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I'm trying to pass a value from my front end to my back end in Node.js as you may know there is not much documentation for Hapi in the net and most of the tutorials use angular.

I want to simply pass a variable from my front end (HTML) to back end in Hapi.

**index.html**

```
 <script>
      $('#messages').submit(function(){
        var word =  $('#m').val();
        //alert(word);
       $('#m').val('');
       return false;
      });

    </script>
  </body>
```

So what should I do here in order to pass the value? Thanks

P.S: I searched but couldn't find questions similar to mine.

Comment: Maybe search the API instead?

Comment: Alright.would you give an example?

Comment: AJAX - > http://hapijs.com/api#requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you do not need jquery to pass the value, the user could do it straight from html form like so:

```html
<form id="messages" action="./your/path/" method="POST">

  Your variable:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="your_variable" value="your_value">
  <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

If you have some reason for using a script use AJAX with $.POST inside the submit() callback:

```js
$('#messages').submit(function() {

  $.post("./your/path/", {
      your_variable: "your_value"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      alert("Data Loaded: " + data); // change for whatever callback you want
    });

  return false;
});
```

Check out [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to read up on $.post more.

And on the back end side, pick up your variable in the handler from request.payload:

```js
server.route([{
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/your/path/',
  config: {
      payload: {
          output: 'data'
      }
  },
  handler: function (request, response){
    var your_variable = request.payload.your_variable
  }
}]);
```

Some useful hapi.js documentation links: [request object](http://hapijs.com/api#request-object), [server route](http://hapijs.com/api#serverrouteoptions), [route configuration](http://hapijs.com/api#route-configuration), [route handler](http://hapijs.com/api#route-handler).

Also, I'd recommend you to refresh your knowledge on HTTP protocol: 
[wikipedia page on HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)
and a new MEAP book on HAPI.js that is avaiable on manning.org - I have learned hapi.js from it, absolutely brilliant: 
[Hapi.js in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/hapi-js-in-action)

Comment: Nice recommendation ;)

Comment: @Alan Finally!thanks man.but i don't understand the negative points for my question.

Comment: @Matt hey man i saw your article http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-and-handling-forms-in-node-js/ it would be better if you did it in a framework and put out the code at the end.

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project :-) - haha, I gave you one positive to ease the pain ;)

Comment: @Mojtaba I didn't write that

Comment: @Matt sorry my bad.but i have seen an article with your name about hapi.i'm sure about that.it was matt-something.com.any way.

Comment: same advice about putting a sample